18B20 Sensor EMI filtering when in parasitic mode
I've fitted an 18B20 sensor to monitor engine temperature in a 4x4 buggy I built. It's operating in parasitic power mode to make use of the single wire that was already in the wiring loom. Every few readings fails (giving -127C). I've tried fitting a 10nF capacitor as that's worked with other sensors on this build, but that stops the readings altogether. Am I doing something wrong?

Sensor connected to an Arduino which then displays the temperature to an LCD
4.7k ohm resistor between the 18B20 data line and 5v on the Arduino
Capacitor is between data line and ground where the data line enters the Arduino
Original DS18B20 sensor from reputable dealer
Sensor is earthed to the engine
I also tried a 100nF capacitor but that also didn't work

I'm planning on rewiring the sensor with screened 3 core cable, using a filtered power supply. But those parts haven't arrived yet.

Yes, the something wrong is adding of capacitor that large to the data bus.
If you add a 10nF capacitor to an open-drain bus with 4k7 pull-up resistor, it makes the RC rise time constant to 47us.
It also means each time any device pulls the bus low, it is longer without parasitic power.
The data sheet also says the RC time constant should be max 15us.
So it makes no sense to add a capacitor of 10nF or 100nF to the bus, it will slow it down so much it can't work.
The maximum total capacitance allowed on bus (chips, cables, filter caps) is about 12nF and even that is achieved with strongest allowed pull-up resistance of 1.5k to 5V.
Of course having the sensor grounded to motor chassis does not help, as who knows what kind of noisy return currents flow in the wires along the route of the current from sensor returning back to your Arduino.
If you want to filter, use much stronger pull-up resistor and much lower capacitance.

Thanks. I'll go ahead with the screened cable, full powered setup, and filtered supply and earth. If that fails I'll try the stronger pull-up and lower capacitor.
